# How can I get access to single chars in strings that are saved in structure while I only have pointer to this structure

Tags: c

I know title sounds weird but I didn't know how to write it. I have simple structure:

```
     struct student_t
    {
     char name[20];
     char surname[40];
     int index;
    };
```

I also have function that have only one argument and it's pointer to this structure. I want to check single chars from string in structure but I don't know how to get to them.

I tried few things

```
      p->name
```

Prints whole string.

```
    *p->name
```

Prints first letter of string.

I thought that by adding numbers to pointer , I can move through string.
But when I try to use

```
     *(p+n)->name
```

it prints 0.

I'm new in C, feel free to hate.

Comment: Its `p->name[n]`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have to use pointers, I cannot use [] operator

Comment: Then `*(p->name + n)`. Pretty stupid restriction I would say when working with arrays...

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's work , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EugeneSh commented: `*(p->name + n)`